# Can't open Android Studio 2.2 anymore

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-2.2

I was trying to start a project on Android Studio. It used to have problems but now it doesn't even open. As said on the terminal:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@619a5dff for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/home/patriciamusmanno/Documentos/musmanno/android/androidat/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /home/patriciamusmanno/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/tmp/jna1982309372201512131.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /home/patriciamusmanno/.AndroidStudio2.2/system/tmp/jna1982309372201512131.tmp
org.picocontainer.defaults.DuplicateComponentKeyRegistrationException: Key com.morcinek.android.codegenerator.plugin.preferences.persistence.TemplateSettings duplicated
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.registerComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$1.extensionAdded(ServiceManagerImpl.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$1.extensionAdded(ServiceManagerImpl.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.addExtensionPointListener(ExtensionPointImpl.java:368)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl.installEP(ServiceManagerImpl.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl.<init>(ServiceManagerImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:499)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:246)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$10.run(ApplicationImpl.java:467)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:101)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:458)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:450)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:197)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
org.picocontainer.defaults.DuplicateComponentKeyRegistrationException: Key com.morcinek.android.codegenerator.plugin.persistence.Settings duplicated
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.registerComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$1.extensionAdded(ServiceManagerImpl.java:91)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$1.extensionAdded(ServiceManagerImpl.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.addExtensionPointListener(ExtensionPointImpl.java:368)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl.installEP(ServiceManagerImpl.java:100)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl.<init>(ServiceManagerImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:220)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:499)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:107)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:90)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectImpl.init(ProjectImpl.java:282)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.initProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:231)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.access$300(ProjectManagerImpl.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl$3.run(ProjectManagerImpl.java:311)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.getDefaultProject(ProjectManagerImpl.java:306)
    at com.intellij.ide.fileTemplates.FileTemplateManager.getDefaultInstance(FileTemplateManager.java:67)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.actions.NewPackageObjectAction.<init>(NewPackageObjectAction.scala:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil.newInstance(ReflectionUtil.java:484)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.convertStub(ActionManagerImpl.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.convert(ActionManagerImpl.java:513)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.getActionImpl(ActionManagerImpl.java:493)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.getAction(ActionManagerImpl.java:486)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.preloadActions(ActionManagerImpl.java:1276)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader.preload(ActionPreloader.java:31)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader$2$1.run(Preloader.java:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.Preloader$2.run(Preloader.java:74)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
^C[ 108744]   WARN - pl.local.NativeFileWatcherImpl - Watcher terminated with exit code 130
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are getting DuplicateComponentKeyRegistrationException so probably fresh re-installation would be the best option.